# Edit with Emacs chrome extension closing windows

Tags: window, frames

I have the edit with emacs chrome extension.

I have emacs open in one frame with multiple windows on different buffers open.  When I am in chrome and focused on a text box I press Alt-Enter. This pops up a new emacs frame and I can edit the text from the text box. When finished I press `C-c C-c` and the frame closes and I go back to my main emacs frame (Ideally at this stage I should go to the browser... ) however one of the windows in my main emacs frame has closed. If I only have one window open in my main emacs frame then I get the message `delete-window: Attempt to delete minibuffer or sole ordinary window`. The text from the edit frame enters the browser text box as expected when I have switched back to the browser.

So it seems the `C-c C-c` command is attempting to close two windows rather than just the new pop up one. How can I stope this, or failing that is there a way to undo the last closed window in my main emacs frame?

Comment: How does the extension invoke emacsclient exactly? Does it use additional software inside Emacs? The error message is expected if you close the last window: why are you saying that this “is attempting to close two windows” when there's only one? But I wonder why `C-c C-c` attempts to close the last window.

Comment: I think the emacs code is here : https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome/blob/master/servers/edit-server.el my understanding is that this should close the pop up frame which contains one new window. But for some reason my main emacs frame has one of its windows closed as well unless it only has one window then I get the delete-window attempt message .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pull request, [Only delete window when not opened in new frame](https://github.com/stsquad/emacs_chrome/pull/140), seems related to the problem you describe. It has been merged but it's not part of a release yet. You can try the development version of the package. If it doesn't fix the problem you should open a new issue on github.